# How can personal and place names be extracted from text using C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, text

Is there any C# algorithm by which personal and place names can be extracted from text?

e.g., given the following text:

```
St. Mark died at Alexandria, in Egypt.  He was martyred, I think.
However, that has nothing to do with my legend.  About the founding of
the city of Venice--
```

(taken from "The Innocents Abroad" by Mark Twain)

...is there any way to extract:

```
St. Mark
Alexandria (or better yet, "Alexandria, Egypt")
Venice
```

?

I realize that there is no way to get 100% accuracy (where all place names and personal names are captured, and no "false positives" are added), but 80% accuracy could be very valuable.

I understand that each word could be compared with an encyclopedia or some such, but there must be a better way. Also, how could the algorithm know to combine "St." and "Mark" and to see "Alexandria, in Egypt" as "Alexandria, Egypt"?

Comment: *“but there must be a better way”* – Why are you that confident about that? How do you recognize names in your mind? Because you *know* the words correspond to names, or even locations. You associate the words with a person or a location; and that’s exactly that a computer program would need to do too. Only way for it to make these associations is by telling it about them, e.g. using an index of names or locations. *“how could the algorithm know to combine ‘St.’ and ‘Mark’”* – Yes, how could it know? You have to tell it to do that.

Comment: First of all, this is not a "c#" specific problem. Secondly, by entering the phrase "extract personal and place names from text algorithm" into google you can find many research papers about what you want to do.

The best thing you could do, without going into full-on NLP is to filter out the obviously not matching words, and try to categorize the rest with something like this: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Comment: wehn you start coding, this might be helpful... 97.114 locations in 249 countries: http://www.unece.org/cefact/codesfortrade/codes_index.html

Comment: This is called "named entity recognition". This might be useful: http://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordNER.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best off using some kind of API that will be able to perform this kind of entity matching, as what you are asking is potentially very complex and requires some degree of semantic textual analysis backed up by a large database. I'd recommend at looking at APIs such as:

[OpenCalais - English Semantic Metadata: Entity/Fact/Event Definitions and Descriptions web-service](http://www.opencalais.com/documentation/calais-web-service-api/api-metadata/entity-index-and-definitions)

> Calais supports a rich set of semantic metadata, including entities, events and facts.

[Alchemy API - Entity Extraction API](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity-extraction)

> AlchemyAPI is capable of identifying people, companies, organizations, cities, geographic features, and other typed entities within your HTML, text, or web-based content. We employ sophisticated statistical algorithms and natural language processing technology to analyze your information, extracting the semantic richness embedded within.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that the links provided here are a bit dated. One project that is still active (and free [correction: GPL, so free for non-commercial]) is the Stanford Natural Language Processing (NLP) libraries (https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/). You can demo their Named Entity Recognition (NER) [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process). It even has a .NET wrapper (https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/).

Microsoft also offers many similar algorithms through Azure Cognitive Services. You would be most interested in Entity Linking (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/entity-linking-intelligence-service/)

I hope helps future viewers.